# Outlook showing unknown Detils

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a machine work with outlook 2013 licensed sometime when the user send to outlook 2003 the receiver get the following details within the message 
  [image]

my question is what is this message ?

Comment: You mean the header of the email?  Every email contains similar information.

Comment: ok this the first time I saw it why it showing ?